# Kubuntu - unable to open remote files with wine

Tags: wine, kubuntu, kde, remote

On Kubuntu 15.04 (and on Linux Mint 17.2 KDE) I am unable to open files from remote shares with wine. It seems Dolphin downloads the file first to a temporary directory and tries to open it from there, which is not what I want. Any idea of a simple workaround?

Comment: Are the remote shares connected by Samba, SFTP, FTP, CIFS...?

Comment: Samba. I also tried SFTP and the result was the same.

Comment: Which program in Wine are you using?

Comment: It's an ERP software my company uses, not well known. It works perfectly in MATE.